# find a function in a integral equation.

Tags: calculus, integration

There is a function " $f$ defined and continuous for a11 real x", which satisfies an equation of the form
$$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt= \int_{x}^{1}t^2f(t)dt + \frac{x^{16}}{8} + \frac{x^{18}}{9} + c$$
where c is a constant. Find an explicit formula for f (x) and find the value of the constant c.

What I do.
Derive both side and get

$$ f(x) = -x^2f(x)+ 2x^{15}+2x^{17}$$
then $$f(x)= \frac{2x^{15}+2x^{17}}{1-x^2}$$ but this function is not continuos for all x real. I made something wrong, some help.

---

Ok. I see my so silly error. $f(x)=2x^{15}$...cause $f(x)= \frac{2x^{15}+2x^{17}}{1+x^2}$

Comment: On the left, in an intermediate step, you have $f(x)\color{red}{+}x^2 f(x)$.

Comment: ha?? ok... so $f(x)= 2x^{15}$.

Comment: Yes, and $c=-\frac19$

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative with respect to $x$:
$$
f(x)=-x^2f(x)+2x^{15}+2x^{17}
$$
from which we get
$$
f(x)=2x^{15}\text{ and }c=-\frac19
$$
Your answer is correct, save for a sign error.